# MySQL password rejected after EasyPHP upgrade

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I have a website that is up and running since many years (almost 10 by now), and hosted by a third party that provided the MySQL database (and connection ID and password I can not change).

To manage changes, I used an old version of EasyPHP `(Apache 1.3.27 - MySQL 4.0.15 - PHP 4.3.3)`, configured to exactly match the online server version.

On the development environment, the MySQL user was set up with `User = ID` as provided by hosting company, `Host = %, Password = pwd` provided by hosting company, `ALL PRIVILEGES and Grant = Yes`.

As expected after so many years, the hosting company announced the migration to newer versions of PHP and MySQL, and to be able to prepare this, I installed a recent version of EasyPHP `(Apache 2.4.7 - MySQL 5.6.15 - PHP 5.4.24)`.

In this new version, I created the MySQL user with PhpMyAdmin (same settings as above, no errors), and set up the same VirtualHosts as before, but none of my scripts are able to connect to the database, returning the classic error:

```
Warning: mysql_connect(): Access denied for user: 'username'@'localhost' (Using password: YES)
```

- Note: in the `mysql_connect()` function, the correct hostname was used, and not `'localhost'` as mentioned in the message error?

Other PHP code is executed correctly, but not very usefull without database connections.
I tried to delete the password, and could connect. Also with `root@localhost and no password`, the connection is made.
But these are no options for the 'real' thing, so I really should be able to connect with the complete connection parameters to emulate the settings of the online server.

For completeness, I also installed and set up UwAmp (Apache 2.2.22 - MySQL 5.6.11 - PHP 5.3.25), and had the same results.

The Windows OS (and/or the 'hosts' file) is also not involved, since the old version of EasyPHP runs correctly on the same box.

<del>Finally, I deleted the user via PhpMyAdmin, and tried to create it back via a PHP mysql_query:</del>

<del>`CREATE USER 'userID'@'hostname' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'password';`</del>

<del>This is throwing the error:</del>

<del>`(1827) The password hash doesn't have the expected format. Check if the correct password algorithm is being used with the PASSWORD() function.`</del>

<del>**Edit:** wrong query, and user created when skipped the `PASSWORD` string in the query. Alas, this user can still not connect tot the database. Why ?</del>

I also played around with `"SET old_passwords=0"` and `"....=1"`, always with the same error.

Has anyone any ideas of the development server settings causing the error, so as to have this to work correctly?

Comment: In version 4.1 MySQL changed the password hashing method. You should read this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/password-hashing.html

Comment: My guess would be that the password column in your database is too short, hence the unexpected format.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider I understand, but MySQL uses the same hashing method when receiving the password from the connection request, doesn't it? And when I checked (`export`) the user, the password is 41 digits long. The `create user`had a typo, and user could be created again, but connection is still rejected.

Answer (score 0):

Here `PASSWORD` clause should not be used:

```
CREATE USER 'userID'@'hostname' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Check [Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-user.html)

Comment: You are right, little typo. Now the user could be created again. Alas, with the same first error...